# Similar Sounding Music

Tags: algorithm, audio

We have a user, with a music library of 100 songs. Out of those he loves 20, he hates 10 and there are 5 he neither hates nor loves. He never listened to the remaining 65.

**Question:** What kind of algorithm(s) is/are used to scan the remaining 65 songs and find out music the user will like?

Comment: Why -2? Is the question too board?

Comment: Is it the Genius in iTunes? ;-)

Comment: Yes, much too broad. An answer could not even begin to describe all the necessary prerequisites necessary for such an algorithm

Comment: yes, something similar

Comment: -3 now, and it's probably because you should be doing your own homework instead of trying to use SO to get someone to do your things for you.

Comment: Well, I am not expecting anyone to write this code, I am just asking for a starting point.

Comment: This is an opinion based question, making it off-topic for SO

Comment: @Jonesy: This is not an opinion based question. I never asked 'what's the best algorithm to do this'. I merely asked for a list of know/available algorithms. While it's heavily down voted (because I am asking a too advance question without any kind of knowledge on the subject) this question is much better for the next visitor than the typical 'please find my bug' question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To suggest new unfamiliar content to a user, the general approach is to use *machine learning*, specifically **[collaborative filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering)**, which is often used for *recommender systems*. The idea is to use the knowledge of the crowd, and finds people (or groups) that have similar taste to yours, and recommend new items that they tend to like.

An alternative is creating a [classification algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) for like/dislike, but that might require extracting features from each song that will describe the essense of the problem, and that's usually not trivial at all.

Some classification algorithms you might want to try are [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), [Naive Bayes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier),  [neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), [Decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm) and more. The real challenge, as I mentioned would be to find the right features for the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I am interested in the 2nd. Can you please provide more details or a starting point?

Comment: @Luka Unfortunately I have no experience on how to extract features for this kind of problem, I have added some classification algorithms you might want to try.

Comment: Okay, thanks fir the help!

Answer (score 2):

Do some research on a product called MusicIP, it had some very clever algorithm fingerprinting technology.  It converted the track to WAV and then created a fingerprint, then some clever magic to match songs that were similar.